# Xamarin Forms editing inside nested ListView

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin.forms

I'm a newbie in these subjects of Xamarin, but have been able to built a good amount amount of features in a personal project to a local Bodyboarding Association that I'm doing for learning purposes. 
But got stuck in one Panel that its making me go crazy.

You can see the attach image that represents the objective of this panel and most of it, is done so far.

The objective:
Is for the user to insert Numeric values in "Entry A", then clicks "Button A" so that each one of the items gets added to the right List "ListView B".
The ListView A is dynamic but has, in max, five elements and all of the Entries must be available for fast filling of the user.

The problem:
Im not being able to make the button to add values into that inner ListView because i'm not able to have the ID of it in the code-behind.
Im using Command & CommandParameter in a MVVM structure.

Is the usage of nested ListView possible this way?

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Why do you need nested listviews?

Comment: I cannot justify that due to lack of knowledge, but, from the first hand, seemed like the best way of relate two lists when i need data entries in the inner List.

Comment: you should never nest ListViews

Comment: So, what should be the correct way of doing this Page ?

Comment: The best way to achieve this is to create a reusable component.

Comment: This is visually complicated and should be impossible from the visual point (how do you scroll horizontally if nothing else???). But if it works visually what's your problem. You have showed almost nothing relevant for that inside your project?

Answer (score 0):

If your outer list items type is something like this

```
public class OuterListItem{
 public string EntryAText { get; set; }
 public ObservableCollection<string> InnerListItems { get; set; }
}
```

On your ViewModel you could have something like this

```
ICommand ButtonCommand = new Command<OuterListItem>((oli) => {
  oli.InnerListItems.Add(oli.EntryAText);
  oli.EntryAText = String.Empty;
});
```

and last on your XAML add an x:Name to your page and the button would look like this

```
<Button Command="{Binding ButtonCommand, Source={x:Reference PageName}}" CommandParameter="{Binding .}"></Button>
```

You need the x:Name and Source attribute to reference a command which is not implemented within the list item.

This way you do not need any ID.